# How to get Twitter user access token to request his email address?

Tags: ionic-framework, twitter

In an Ionic app, I am using [twitter-connect-plugin](https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin) to enable users to authenticate to the app using their twitter account.
The result returned by this plugin includes the authenticated user twitter account Id, username and his picture.
In addition to these fields I also need to retrieve the email address.

I tried to use twitter API v2, by calling the `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id` endpoint. But from [the v2 docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-id) the email address is not included in the user fields.

In the Twitter API v1.1, the `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json` endpoint has the `include_email` parameter, but from [the v1.1 docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials) it requires the user access token:

> **Please note** - Your app will need to regenerate the user access tokens
> for previously authenticated users to access their email address

Any idea on how to get the user access token in the v1.1 in order to use it in the GET account/verify_credentials request?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for that plugin, once you've called `.login` you get back a response.

```
The login reponse object is defined as:

{
  userName: '<Twitter User Name>',
  userId: '<Twitter User Id>',
  secret: '<Twitter Oauth Secret>',
  token: '<Twitter Oauth Token>'
 }
```

You should be able to use the secret and token values from that response object to call the `verify_credentials` endpoint.

Note that this plugin appears to rely on Twitter Kit, which is no longer supported and may stop working in future.